# adding to elements in array of objects using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, heatmap, apexcharts

```
const roomData = [{
        name: 1,
        data: [{
                x: 102,
                y: 35
            },
            {
                x: 105,
                y: 40
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 2,
        data: [{
            x: 104,
            y: 36
        }, {
            x: 105,
            y: 40
        }]
    }
}
```

This is my array.

```
(response.data).forEach((room) => {
            setRoomData(roomData => [...roomData, {
                name: room['floor'],
                data: [{
                    x: room['Roomnumber'],
                    y: room['room_temperature']
                }]
            }]);
```

This is how I set RoomData.
        I need to add another x and y pair in data property on fetching.How to do this using react hooks ?

Comment: add on what action? on clicking something or are you fetching something again?

Comment: Add it to which entry?

Answer (score 1):

So to add data to room(s) with name of `roomToChange` you can use Array.prototype.map:

```
roomData.map((room) =>
  room.name === roomToChange
    ? { ...room, data: room.data.concat(extraItem) }
    : room
);
```